# How to execute a command line from Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to run/execute a command line from a Google Chrome Extension?

For example, an user clicks on specific link and a local shell program is automatically executed.

Currently, my need concerns only Mac OS X.

Merci a lot !

Comment: did you develop anything like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you can solve your problem with this post from google groups
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/WaG-xr-jzaQ

Specially this:

> You will have to use the Native Messaging API. It is more involved
> than just calling a function. You have to build an executable (the
> native host, in native code, like C++) that Chrome will start and use
> Chrome APIs to communicate with it. The native host is run with the
> same privileges as Chrome and can do or executes whatever it wants (as
> long as Chrome can, obviously).

For more information https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/native-messaging